# Track ref's innerHTML in solidjs

Tags: ref, solid-js

I want to be able to track changes in ref's innerHTML via createMemo or createEffect, but for some reason neither of them react to changes. I think I'm missing something...

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createEffect, createMemo, on } from "solid-js";

function App() {
  let divRef;

  const memo = createMemo(() => {
    console.log("this is memo: ", divRef?.innerHTML);
    return divRef?.innerHTML;
  });

  createEffect(() => {
    console.log("this it effect: ", divRef?.innerHTML);
  });

  return (
    <div contenteditable={true} ref={divRef}>
      this is editable conent
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I expect innerHTML to be printed to console every time it changes, but it doesn't work for some reason.
Link to sandbox: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/2cfc96b3-69c9-406a-a132-714703e844d9

Answer (score 1):

In Solid you can track signals only, not DOM elements, however you can use signals to set DOM values achieving the same result.

```js
function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = createSignal("Initial Content");

  return (
    <div>{content}</div>
  );
}
```

Now, whenever you update the content via `setContent`, div will have the new value as its innerHTML.